# Python: add item in multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, find

hi I am not very knowledgeable in python. I want to insert the numbers into the multidimensional array (c), with a maximum difference of 0.21% between numbers. However, I want to put the other related numbers of the numbers that are .21 different from each other into the same array.

```
nums = sorted([47255, 47343, 47865, 47904, 48000, 48001], reverse=True)

i = 0
b = 1

c = []

while i < len(nums):
    while b < len(nums) - i:
        a = ((nums[i] - nums[i+b]) / nums[i+b]) * 100
        if a < 0.21:
            if (nums[i] in x for x in c):
                c.append([])
                c[i].append(str(nums[i]))
                c[i].append(str(nums[i + b]))
            else:
                c.append(str(nums[i]))
                c.append(str(nums[i + b]))
                c.append([])
        b = b + 1
    b = 1
    i = i + 1
print(c)
```

result:

```
[['48001', '48000', '48001', '47904'], ['48000', '47904'], ['47904', '47865'], [], ['47343', '47255']]
```

what i want

```
[['48001', '48000', '47904', '47865'], ['47343', '47255']]
```

(48001 48000 max difference %0.21 but more difference %0.21 48001 between 47865) but 47865 .21 47904 .21 48000 and this too max .21 48001 All of these numbers must be in index 1 of the c array.

47343 not max difference .21 47865 then this should also be in the second index.

47343 max %0.21 difference 47255

```
c = [['48001', '48000', '47904', '47865'], ['47343', '47255']]
```

[img please look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK9K4.jpg)
I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that I got the question right, I have a solution. 
The algorithm is simple - when adding a new element in the matrix:

- Test every element of every existing array if it meets the (*0.21%*) condition with the new number

  - If yes, add the new number to that array
  - If the number was not added to any array (no existing numbers met the condition), create a new array only containing the new number

*code00.py*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


def add_to_array(n, arr2d, ratio=0.0021):
    for arr in arr2d:
        for elem in arr:
            if abs(n - elem) / max(n, elem) <= ratio:
                arr.append(n)
                return
    arr2d.append([n])


def main(*argv):
    nums = sorted([47255, 47343, 47865, 47904, 48000, 48001], reverse=True)
    c = []
    for n in nums:
        add_to_array(n, c)
    print("The matrix:", c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066411225]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> The matrix: [[48001, 48000, 47904, 47865], [47343, 47255]]
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: that's right thanks. it's just too complicated for me. I am trying to understand

Comment: I think your version is more complicated. I also explained the algorithm. You can always print intermediary values in order to get an idea of what happens inside an algorithm (for example you could add `print(n, arr2d)` as the 1st line of *add\_to\_array*) to see how it gets filled.